# Which tension can be accounted to cause stress on an elementary part?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, elasticity, stress-strain

suppose a rod of length $l$ and mass $m$ is hanging from a ceiling whose young's modulus is $Y$.

we have to calculate elongation in it due its own weight.

[image]

now to write equation of stress for this elementary part which tension can be said to cause stress   $T$ or $T+dT$ so that stress = force/area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your elementary part to be so small that the difference in tension on top and bottom can be neglected as it does not contribute significantly to the elongation compared to the much larger forces acting on it.

Find the elongation on this small element using Hooke's law and integrate to find the total elongation. Il leave it to you to fill in the gaps, hope this was a good enough hint.

Comment: But won't the difference of tension be supporting its weight (elementary part)

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-rope-of-length-l-and-mass-m-is-hanging-from-a-rigid-support-the/ here in this question we don't neglect wieght of elementary part

Comment: The tension in a hanging rod at each point due to the weight of the rod below that point is, (ρAh)g, where, h, is measured up from the bottom.

Comment: @JustJohan please add your comment about how weight can be neglected over the larger forces of tension in your answer so i can approve it